# jQuery: Changing 'id' with .attr('id', 'val') won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr

First of all, the code has been simplified and only contains the essential parts.

So I have the following HTML file (single_lesson.html):

```
<tr class="my_lessons">
    <td>
        <select name="my_von" id="my_von"></select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to change `id` of `#my_von` to `#my_von1` with the following jQuery-code:

```
jQuery.get('single_lesson.html', function(my_html)
{
    jQuery(my_html).children().children('#my_von').attr('id', 'my_von1');
}, 'html');
```

It won't work and I have no idea why.

---

The line `console.log(jQuery(my_html).children().children('#my_von'));` gives the following array:

```
[select#my_von, prevObject: e.fn.init[7], context: undefined, jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function, selector: ""…]
```

If I open this array there's another array called `select#my_von`. If I open this one there are several fields and `id: "my_von"` is one of them. The field `id` is there, so I see no reason why it won't change.

Comment: You're getting the HTML as a string, and then wrapping it `jQuery(my_html)`, then you change the ID, but you're not doing anything with the jQuery object, and the original string won't be changed, so wrapping it again, you get the exact same output ?

Comment: you are not changing the content of `my_html`, the id will be updated in the dom object created by calling `jQuery(my_html)` but it won't be updated in the string stored in `my_html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny) for your comment. I didn't realize `jQuery(my_html)` is an object. I solved the problem by simply storing the object `jQuery(my_html)` as a variable and then storing its HTML contents as an other variable after changing `id`. My code is below:

```
var my_html_jquery = jQuery(my_html);
my_html_jquery.children().children('#my_von').attr('id', 'my_von1');
my_html = my_html_jquery.html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use `children().children()`, especially with a potentially unknown DOM structure (and when an ID lookup is as fast as it gets).

The usual problem is multiple top level elements in the get result or it is not valid HTML starting with a `<`. The easiest fix is to wrap it in a dummy element first:

```
jQuery.get('single_lesson.html', function(my_html)
{
      var $div = jQuery('<div>').html(my_html);
      $div.find('#my_von').attr('id', 'my_von1');
      // Now do whatever you want to do with $div.html() or $div.children();
}, 'html');
```

Comment: @adeneo : That's what I get for cut & paste... corrected :)